# Change order of additional lookup field in display form

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, lookup-column, list-form, 2019

I created lookup field with additional column at the end of creating list columns. Now I would like set another order of the additional field in forms, but when I set order of lookup column in list settings, the additional column stay in display form still at the end.

I tried do it in Designer or via content types, but anything is not work. Is it possible?

Comment: which version of SharePoint are you using? Are you using classic or modern experience?

Comment: 2019, classic experience (can not switch to modern)

Comment: Just want to confirm, did you try to change the column order from list settings and content type settings (if any settings available)?

Comment: Ok, i am stupid, but today, when turn on content types, i can do it. Thanks for help.

Comment: Is it working for you now?

Comment: yes, now i can reorder main, even additional lookup column

Comment: Great, I have added an answer below with explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try reordering list form columns using below methods:

**List settings > Columns section**:

1. Go to list settings
2. Scroll down to "Columns" section
3. Select "Column ordering" option
4. Change the order of columns and click "OK" button to save changes

**Content Type settings**:

1. Go to the list settings page
2. Click "Advanced settings"
3. Select "Yes" against "Allow management of content types?" option
4. Scroll down and click "OK" to save changes.
5. From list settings page, scroll down to "Content Types" section. Click the content type name for which you want to change the order of columns (Default list content type is named "Item").
6. Select "Column order" option at the bottom of content type settings page
7. Change the order of columns and click "OK" button to save changes
8. Go back to List settings > Advanced settings and set "Allow management of content types?" option to "No".